# Registry Handling in Cpp

Tags: c++, winapi

I am working on the code in wherin i have to get the data under the particular regitry path..For this i m using the fnctions to open the key and subkey as
`RegOpenKeyEx (HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE, sk, NULL, KEY_READ, &hKey);`
which on debugging giving me unused value handle to the path i need to access.
What is going wrong here ? can anybody tell me ?

```
void GetAlgorithmList()
{
    HKEY hKey=0;

    LPCTSTR sk = TEXT("SOFTWARE\\ALGORITHM");


    LONG openRes=RegOpenKeyEx (HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE,sk,NULL,KEY_READ   ,&hKey);

    long lret;
    PVALENT val_list=0;

    unsigned long totalsize = 1000;
    lret = 0;

    LPWSTR szValueBuf=NULL;

    lret = RegQueryMultipleValues(hKey,val_list,totalsize,szValueBuf,&totalsize);
    if (lret == ERROR_SUCCESS)
    {
        printf("Success 1");
    }
     FILE* pFile = fopen("D:\\HinalH\\logFile.txt", "a+");
    fopen("D:\\logFile.txt", "a+");
    fprintf(pFile, "%d\n",szValueBuf);
    fclose(pFile);

    RegCloseKey(hKey);

}
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: `RegOpenKeyEx` can fail. You should test for it. If it failed you can get extended information about the error. Take a look in the documentation. **If the function fails, the return value is a nonzero error code defined in Winerror.h. You can use the FormatMessage function with the FORMAT_MESSAGE_FROM_SYSTEM flag to get a generic description of the error.**

Comment: i dont get any error while building my program..The problem is i should get handle to keys and subkeys i ma inputing through RegOpenKeyEx .but i get unused value 0*00000f0 as a output.

Comment: what do you get in `LONG openRes`? If this is nonzero, it is an error code. Of course in this case you will not get a valid handle back.

Comment: I get zero value in LONG openRes

Comment: congratulation, this means opening was at least successful. you should check now what you get in `lret = RegQueryMultipleValues`. Please remember if the function fails this contain an error code. You can find out some about the kind of error with aid of it.

Comment: the handle will come back in `hKey`. please note that you give a pointer inside `RegOpenKeyEx` for that matter.

Comment: I get zero in lret as weell..But i get bad pointer in szValueBuf and the programs breaks as son it comes out of RegQueryMultipleValues.

Comment: Take a look what you are giving inside the function `RegQueryMultipleValues`. This seems to be wrong. Note my updated answer too.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**First:** You should check the result of `RegOpenKeyEx`. Please read the documentation more carefully. Its really necessary to handle errors if they occur at runtime.

**Second:** Please take a look to the documentation for function [RegQueryMultipleValues](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms724905%28v=vs.85%29.aspx).
Just take your attention to the `val_list` parameter and to the `lpValueBuf` parameter both are out parameter. I cannot see that you handle them in the right way in your code.

**Third:** I cannot find any sample using [RegQueryMultipleValues](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms724905%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) in the web. I played a little arround and created a working example.

Here is the sample I did.

```
#include <Windows.h>
#include <string>
#include <stdlib.h>

#define MY_KEY TEXT("SYSTEM\\CurrentControlSet\\services\\BITS")

int _tmain(int argc, _TCHAR* argv[])
{
    HKEY hKey;
    LONG lResult;

    lResult = RegOpenKeyEx(HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE, MY_KEY, 0, KEY_READ, &hKey);

    if(lResult == ERROR_SUCCESS)
    {
        VALENT val_list[4];
        memset(val_list, 0, sizeof(val_list));

        val_list[0].ve_valuename = TEXT("ImagePath");
        val_list[1].ve_valuename = TEXT("Start");
        val_list[2].ve_valuename = TEXT("DisplayName");
        val_list[3].ve_valuename = TEXT("FailureActions");

        DWORD totalsize = 0;

        RegQueryMultipleValues(hKey, val_list, sizeof(val_list)/sizeof(VALENT), NULL, &totalsize);

        LPWSTR lpBuffer = (LPWSTR)malloc(totalsize);
        if (lpBuffer == NULL)
        {
            // TODO: Error handling
        }

        lResult = RegQueryMultipleValues(hKey, val_list, sizeof(val_list)/sizeof(VALENT), lpBuffer, &totalsize);
        if (lResult == ERROR_SUCCESS)
        {
            for (int i = 0; i < sizeof(val_list)/sizeof(VALENT); i++)
            {
                DWORD len = val_list[i].ve_valuelen;
                DWORD *ptr = (DWORD *)val_list[i].ve_valueptr;

                if (val_list[i].ve_type == REG_SZ || val_list[i].ve_type == REG_EXPAND_SZ)
                {
                    printf("len:%d content:\"%S\"\n", len, ptr);
                }
                else if (val_list[i].ve_type == REG_DWORD)
                {
                    printf("len:%d content:\"%08x\"\n", len, *ptr);
                }
                else if (val_list[i].ve_type == REG_BINARY)
                {
                    printf("len:%d\n", len);
                    for (unsigned k = 0; k < len; k++) printf("%02x ", ((BYTE *)ptr)[k]);
                }
                else
                {
                    // TODO: implement more
                }
            }
        }

        free(lpBuffer);
        RegCloseKey(hKey);
    }
    else
    {
        // TODO: Error handling
    }

    return 0;
}
```

To be honest for me it seems this function is not the best option to access information in the registry. Better you should use functions like [RegQueryValueEx](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms724911%28v=vs.85%29.aspx).

Comment: it should store the result in szValueBuf. m i getting it right?

Comment: you need to init the `VALENT` structures and you need to reserve enough memory for the result. in my answer you find a working example for a special RegistryKey.

Comment: yes..i tried doing it your way..that worked..Now the only problem i facing is,instead of getting number value, i should b able to print the string that data for the particular vlaue contains.

Comment: after you successfully called `RegQueryMultipleValues` you will find all values stored in the `val_list` structures. There is also a member in this structure telling you the size and the type of this value. you have to use this to do the further operations.

Comment: one more query...How to convert  LPWSTR lpBuffer to string..i want to copy the content of  LPWSTR lpBuffer into a text file.

Comment: take care, the buffer where `lpBuffer` point to hold the information for the complete query. if you want to access element by element you have to use the pointer in the `val_list` structures. you also find information about the size of this element in bytes. i will try to create an example for the code above and update.

Comment: Thank you so much for your help! Your code helped me alot..Thank you once again!

Comment: Can we do you something like, wihtout testing the value name in our code..can we get it dynamically and then pass it to RegQueryMultipleValues and then do the futhur implementation

Comment: Yes you can do this. Take a look [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms724862(v=vs.85).aspx) and [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms724865(v=vs.85).aspx).